# Registered through Facebook/OpenID login. Would prefer to login directly without 3rd party now

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, login

I opened my Stack Overflow account by logging in through Facebook.

I would prefer **not** to use Google/OpenID/Facebook, and instead login directly with an email address (one that is not associated with any Google/Facebook/etc account).

Is it possible to now change this association?  I can't seem to do it through 'my logins', as that only allows me to associate my account with other login services.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange is itself an OpenID provider ([blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/)). Go to [openid.stackexchange.com](https://openid.stackexchange.com/)

Set up an account and then add that via the "my logins" link on your profile page.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange supports OpenID logins only - no "normal" user/password logins.

You could host your own OpenID provider software (e.g. SimpleID) or use one of the other OpenID providers out there. See [My OpenID provider is shutting down; how do I change my Stack Exchange login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95137/my-openid-provider-is-shutting-down-what-do-i-do/95200#95200) for OpenID provider selection hints.