# I can't login using MyOpenID, Google or Stack Exchange accounts nor recover Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, myopenid, account-recovery

My [MyOpenID](http://myopenid.com/) login is working right in *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*, but I can't log in to Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow using MyOpenID, Google nor Stack Exchange. The only page I see is the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" one.

If I try to create an new Stack Exchange account using my email, it says this email is already registered. If I try to recover my account, it says:

> Someone requested an account recovery on Stack Overflow for
> myemailaddress@gmail.com, but we don’t have an account on this site
> that matches this email address.
>
> But you have an account on these other sites:
>
> Stack Overflow
>
> Ask Ubuntu

It makes no sense.

I've already tried to change browser and turn on cookies, as said here:
[Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)
But my MyOpenID is working in *Ask Ubuntu*.

My user is: https://stackexchange.com/users/1474753/yuric

Comment: Strange... Magically now I'm able to login with MyOpenID and with Stack Exchange account to Meta StackoverFlow. But not to StackoverFlow ("Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page, as usual)... Unfortunately, I can't figure out why this is working out now. I'm using one of the same browsers I've used before for testing...

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know this. Thanks. Anyway, I still can't login to StackOverflow using my StackExchange account, nor using my Google account. But it works when logging in to Meta StackOverflow and AskUbuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I'm logged in! Well, the solution came from something I've already tested: enabling cookies! ([Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)). In fact, the first time I tried it I had set a permission to *stackoverflow.com* to create cookies. But it was useless, because my default configuration is to let sites define cookies. But I set cookies to be delete every time Firefox closes and do not allow third-party cookies.

The different steps I took:

- Cleaned Firefox's last hour cookies, cache, offline sites data and sites preferences.
- **I've set my Firefox browser to allow third-party cookies**.
- And I've restarted Firefox (But I don't know if this is strictly needed or not).

Since I could log in for the first time, I'm now able to login even if not allowing third-party cookies.

It was hard to imagine this error from a "Ooops" message... And I still can't figure out why it worked firstly for Meta Stack Overflow... It is fixed, anyway. Thanks you all.