# myOpenID ending...what login should I use?

Tags: support

I got an email this morning that myOpenID is ending Feb 2014.  How anyone else received this?  Is it real?

If so, what login do I use for stackexchange/stackoverflow?  Is there a way to migrate/transfer into another login so I don't use all of my reputation points?

Comment: myopenid has been dying for some time now. Add another OpenID account, you could use https://openid.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Heavily related (or another dup): [MyOpenID no longer supported; add alternative login method to your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442/182513)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is real.

[myOpenId is indeed coming to an end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442/182513). You need to use any other open ID provider (Facebook, Yahoo, Google or even the Stack Exchange one). These are all linked in the login page.

You can add another Open Id provider by going to your account and clicking on the "my logins" link:

[image: my logins]

The popup has a link to add logins.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I just added a stackexchange openid account.  Will it continue using my username (4thSpace)?  I did type that in as the name part.

Comment: @4thSpace - that won't change. It is just a name associated with the login, not your user name on the site.