# Will/Does SO/SE support any way to migrate accounts from myOpenID

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid, myopenid

myOpenID have announced they are closing from February 2014.

All my SE accounts are linked using a single myOpenID id and I'm sure many thousands of others have the same situation. How are we advised to proceed to avoid losing information and maintain linked accounts on SE?

oops, dupe: [myOpenID shuts down February 1, 2014; add an alternative login method to your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account?rq=1)

Comment: Since SO meta is the page I get taken to from the "meta" link on the main SE site, I assume it _is_ actually the meta for all of SE?

Comment: We don't currently have a meta.stackexchange.com - so meta.stackoverflow.com is the place for network wide issues as well.

Comment: And yes, you need to add another login method. We did email everyone who had only myOpenID (and provided an email) telling them they need to do this.

Comment: I thought I only had OpenID, but upon checking I added another one without realising ;)