# Show X more comments bug when reviewing a low quality post

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, review

I noted a possible minor bug about comments when reviewing a [low quality post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3038164). The *bug* is that after clicking on *Show X more comments*, while the comments are correctly displayed, the message *Show X more comments* doesn't disappear (I thought at first that other comments were added after I have clicked, but no).

Before clicking *Show 2 more comments*:

> [image]

After clicking *Show 2 more comments* (button is still here but there is no more comments to display)

> [image]

Comment: The whole "more comments" thing is messed up. For example click [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account#comment594376_190442) - you will see the list of comments expanded but yet there is the "add / show 9 more comments" that when clicked just change the sort of the comments, not loading any more comments.

Comment: This isn't just happening when reviewing a low quality post. Wasn't working on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python) question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of several bugs introduced by some new code in the comments system.  *mea culpa*!  These should be fixed now.

Comment: I confirm that I am no longer able to reproduce it. Thanks for quick fixing.