# "Show n more comments" does not disappear if not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I've noticed that since a few days (weeks?), the "Show n more comments" link at the bottom of the comment chain does not disappear after clicking. The comments are correctly loaded, the link just doesn't disappear (and upon click, a new network request is initiated again).

This happens on every site in the Stack Exchange network when you're not logged in for the website.

To verify this bug, just open an incognito window and pick a post with lots of comments.

Comment: I can reproduced the bug.

Comment: [status-reproduced] here too, Win7 Chrome 29.0.1547.76

Comment: It's probably not browser or OS-specific, as I've also tested it with Firefox 23 and Chromium 29 on Linux.

Comment: What's the over/under on @BenCollins having a coronary dealing with inconsequential comment bugs?

Comment: I do not have this bug on FF23.0.1 or IE8 (Both with caches cleared beforehand)

Comment: @Amber I just tested it in IE8 as well and I *do* see the bug. Are you sure that you were not logged in on the site you were testing?

Comment: @RobW I have never logged in on Stack Exchange sites on IE, I tried it on Meta and it didn't show the bug, I just now tried it on SO and Unix Exchange, and it gave the bug on both of them.

Comment: I have also reported something similar here [Show X more comments bug when reviewing a low quality post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198960/show-x-more-comments-bug-when-reviewing-a-low-quality-post). It seems there are some troubles with comments (see comments on my question), that happen logged or not (and not only when reviewing posts like I was thinking at first).

Comment: Also happens for me when I'm logged in for protected questions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't know about a coronary, but it certainly has been keeping me on edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some newly refactored comment code has been running (off and on) for a few days, and there have been a few bugs manifested in the new code.  Still working through it, but this one should be fixed.

Comment: Can you decorate my question with the `[status-completed]` tag?

Comment: @BenCollins I don't know if all issues are fixed, but for sure, the issue I have reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198960/show-x-more-comments-bug-when-reviewing-a-low-quality-post), and other issues reported in comments, are also no longer reproducible. Thanks for fixing, and maybe you should also answer to my question, so I can upvote, and "decorate" my question with the [status-completed] tag.

Comment: @Ben I've noticed that the bug still happens when you're not logged in AND browsing on the mobile site.