# "Show more comments" link doesn't disappear when clicked on deleted question

Tags: bug, comments

See this question: [PDF parsing library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android/)

Below the question, there is the link to show more comments: "show 1 more comments"

Putting aside the issue with [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) since that will never change, the link still stays shown after clicking it.

Comment: related: [show-n-more-comments-does-not-disappear-if-not-logged-in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199009/)