# Link "Show more comments" does not disappear on mobile devices

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

I noticed that the same bug marked as fixed (status-complete) [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199009/show-n-more-comments-does-not-disappear-if-not-logged-in) still exists when using a mobile device:

When I'm not logged-in, and click the "Show N more comments" link, then:

- the hidden coments are show
- the "Show N more comments" link stays visible
- when I click the link again, I get a small yellow popup with the message "Commenting requires an account with 50 reputation"

I reproduced this bug on an android 4.3 device with both the latest Chrome and the standard android browser.

Comment: Yup, reproduced on desktop machine with latest Chrome. The other bug was fixed for the full site theme, but there's still a bug in the mobile theme which is using different JS files.