# Steps (with screen shots) to merge MyOpenID account into social network accounts/email providers accounts

Tags: support, openid, google, authentication, myopenid

If you have taken the time to merge your MyOpenID StackOverflow (and StackExchange) account into a social network account such as Google or Facebook, can you describe the workflow (maybe with screen shots)?  Many will be confused on February 1, 2014, so I thought having a question and some answers with a solution will be nice to have.  I will take the time soon and do it myself.  **I'm sure there will be answers for the following account types, unless someone takes the time to answer for all of them.  Facebook, Google, Twitter, LinkedIn, Yahoo**

Note, this question doesn't show you the steps to merge, so it's not entirely helpful to save hundreds of millions of users time.

[myOpenID shuts down February 1, 2014; add an alternative login method to your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account)

**See this for reference:**

https://www.myopenid.com/

**Quote from site above:**

We have made the decision to end of life myOpenID, and the service will be turned off on February 1, 2014.

In 2006 Janrain created myOpenID to fulfill our vision to make registration and login easier on the web for people. Since that time, social networks and email providers such as Facebook, Google, Twitter, LinkedIn and Yahoo! have embraced open identity standards. And now, billions of people who have created accounts with these services can use their identities to easily register and login to sites across the web in the way myOpenID was intended.

By 2009 it had become obvious that the vast majority of consumers would prefer to utilize an existing identity from a recognized provider rather than create their own myOpenID account. As a result, our business focus changed to address this desire, and we introduced social login technology. While the technology is slightly different from where we were in 2006, we are confident that we are still delivering on our initial promise - that people should take control of their online identity and are empowered to carry those identities with them as they navigate the web.

For those of you who still actively use myOpenID, we can understand your disappointment to hear this news and apologize if this causes you any inconvenience. To reduce this inconvenience, we are delaying the end of life of the service until February 1, 2014 to give you time to begin using other identities on those sites where you use myOpenID today.

Comment: What do you mean by merging into social network accounts? Instructions for adding other logins to Stack Exchange profiles (with screenshots) are available in [the post you linked to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account).

Comment: My suggestion is to move the answer (stuff in bold) to an actual answer.  Why does the answer live in the question body?  It doesn't make any sense the way that question is structured.

Comment: This is meta. The usual Q&A rules are sometimes bent around here. :) That post was intended as an instructional announcement and it certainly did the job. I don't think we need to duplicate it for the sake of question/answer separation and then have two places to maintain and keep accurate.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure.  Bending the rules in Meta StackExchange seems like a sin to me.  :-)  I may comment on the duplicate later if it doesn't get fixed.  I really think the owner of MyOpenID should send an email (to those with a MyOpenID account) once a month until Feb. 1 until notifying users to read the question to that question.

Comment: We already emailed everyone who didn't have any other credentials on file. It wasn't as big a number of users as you might think. :)

Comment: Gotcha.  How many were there?  I use a junk email account, because when I first started with StackExchange, I treated it like any other website that I can't trust with spam.  Now I trust it a little more.  So that's why I didn't see the email.

Comment: I don't remember anymore, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Answer made clear:

**To avoid getting locked out of your Stack Exchange account, we strongly suggest that anyone using myOpenID as their primary (or even backup) login add a new login method to their Stack Exchange account.**

We're also going to remove the "myOpenID" button from the sign-up/login page soon, in order to discourage new users from signing up using myOpenID.

Here's how to add a new login to your account. You must be logged into your account when you begin. (This information is also available [in the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials).)

Open up your user profile page (by clicking on your login name at the top of the screen) and click the "my logins" link above the bio box on the right hand side.
[image: my logins]

You should see a list of all of your logins.

To add a new login, click "add more logins..." at the bottom of the box. Choose the new login from the list and follow the steps to confirm. 
[image: edit logins]

If you choose, you can remove your myOpenID login by clicking the same "my logins" link, then clicking "remove" next to myOpenID.

If you are adding a Stack Exchange OpenID, you will receive a confirmation email. You must click the link in the email to confirm your email address before the Stack Exchange OpenID will show up under "my logins". Please make sure that you are already logged into your account when you click the confirmation link; otherwise, you will create a new account that needs to be merged with your old one.

---

**If you encounter any trouble adding logins, or accidentally create a separate account that you would like merged, please fill out our [contact form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).**