# I lost all my data and reputation in SO

Tags: support, openid, merge-accounts

I know that this question has been asked before, but today when I logged into StackOverflow all my profile was gone: questions, reputation, profile data, everything! Can someone give me a hand on this?

It only happened to me in StackOverflow AFAIK, since here in Meta I still have all my data.

Thanks

Comment: Your account is still here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/270293/oscar-carballal

Comment: not really, when I login I get this profile: http://i.imgur.com/w5PZsQP.png

Comment: Sounds like you have your sign-ins borked.

Comment: @Mysticial sorry for the question, what do you mean by borked?

Comment: Well, I think you simply need the accounts merged, which can be asked for, I think it's somewhere in the help center. Any chance that you changed your openID recently?

Comment: @tohecz nope, I didn't change my OpenID, but I haven't logged in since three months ago, I don't know if that can affect in any way

Comment: @OscarCarballal: It looks like you registered a [new account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3071464/) today. Did you?

Comment: @AmalMurali not at all, I just logged in from MyOpenID as usual, and it redirected me to a new profile in SO, instead of the usual profile

Comment: I'm confused - you posted this from the account you can't see?

Comment: @Flexo Yes, my account isn't accesible in SO, but in Meta it's working perfectly.

Comment: On SO at least the two accounts have very different openids associated.

Comment: Both should be pizte.myopenid.com, that's the only openid account I have

Comment: It isn't showing that to me on anything but the 1 Rep account. And the Meta account is showing the same as the main one. I'd take a look at the settings on your Meta account, log out on main and then try logging back in with the provider you see on your Meta account currently.

Comment: Strange, my meta account shows google as provider, and when I log in in SO with google it works fine. I'm wondering how the hell did it change from myopenid to google. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no add openid event in your history for anything but the older one. There's a login event on the 20th from your email providers openid. It's the same as the email set in your email field, so I *think* (but I'm guessing) that because your email provider's openid is seen as authoritative for that address it might have been sufficient to authorize you for the whole account. Surprised that it seems to have  usurped the other openid though. (I could be misreading the log though)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once upon a time, you used MyOpenID to log in on Stack Overflow. But back in August, you removed that credential from your account, adding instead a Google account and relying on that to authenticate you.

Then, today, you tried to log in with your MyOpenID credentials again. Since those were no longer associated with your account, a new account was created.

I've merged these accounts. You can now access the same account using either Google or MyOpenID.

However, MyOpenID is [going away in February](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account), so... Don't count on that working for too much longer.