# Why remove myOpenID two weeks before deprecation?

Tags: support, openid

I had trouble logging in this evening because the log in button for myOpenID was removed, even though the service will still be available for the rest of the month.  Why was this done prematurely?

I'm still weighing my options for a replacement, and I don't find any of the alternatives particularly attractive.

Comment: If you sign up now, who's to blame when it's gone two weeks from now knowing it would be gone two weeks from now? That's a short time frame to drop that news. At least it was there for years while it was spotty.

Comment: @random: If you were to try to sign up for a myOpenID account now, you'd see the warning banners quite prominently.

Answer (score 10):

It's not actually *up* most of the time even though it's supposed to still be operational.

We don't want to even implicitly encourage people to sign up with myOpenID, so we removed the button. You can still sign in with it (assuming the service works) entering your myOpenID URL manually after clicking "show more login options" on the login page.

Far as alternatives go, may I suggest our very own [Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Citation needed for the "not up most of the time" claim; I use SO almost daily and haven't had a problem in years.  I, unfortunately, don't know my myOpenID URL, so losing the button was awkward.  I tried a Stack Exchange OpenID a couple years ago, and had problems getting it connected to my existing account.  I'll have to check that out again to see if I can get it to work this time.

Comment: Once you're logged into Stack, you don't keep logging back into myOpenID unless you log out of Stack or Stack logs you out. Either way, you can spend months using your Stack account without ever having to relogin via myOpenID, but when you do, it's going to be down, on the fritz, or maybe up @adr

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy We have some instructions up [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac).

Comment: @random:  You mean you don't clear your cookies every day?

Comment: "We don't want to even implicitly encourage people to sign up with myOpenID."  You can't actually create a new myOpenID account now because of the pending deprecation.  Making it harder for people to sign in with their existing account is a bug.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'm sure there are people out there with existing myOpenID accounts who aren't using our sites yet.

Comment: @Anna Lear:  Which is why this approach might be more appropriate:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac/216114#216114