# Google's OpenID implementation works where Stack Exchange's doesn't ('Detected an attempt to send an assertion...')

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-openid

Now that [MyOpenID](http://myopenid.com/) [ceases to exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac) (officially, it is today), I tried to add the Stack Exchange OpenID to my account at [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge). It failed for the Stack Exchange OpenID, but it *worked using the Google OpenID*.

---

#### Doing it

[image: Screenshot: Initial screen for adding the Stack Exchange OpenID at SourceForge]

[image: Screenshot: start adding the Stack Exchange OpenID to a SourceForge accound: entering the SourceForge password, the Stack Exchange OpenID and pressing the button "Log in".]

---

#### Crashed and burned

After entering the email address and password (as for a normal login at a Stack Exchange site), I get the error

> *Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.*,

[image: Screenshot: Stack Exchange OpenID throws an error]

I tried with Firefox (with [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)) and Google Chrome. I also tried restarting the browsers and tried logging out from all Stack Exchange sites prior to an attempt.

#### Resolution?

Is this a bug in the Stack Exchange OpenID implementation, and is there a work-around?

Comment: This is about the workings of Stack Exchange OpenID thingy. Though it is not related to any particular Stack Exchange site, it is related to the OpenID implementation by the Stack Exchange OpenID thingy. That is what the tag "stackexchange-openid" is for, right?