# Careers account not linked since OpenID expiry

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, login

When prompted about the [MyOpenID switch off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac), I added a Google account as my [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) provider for Stack Overflow.

That works fine, however I've gone into Careers for the first time since the switch and logged in with the Google account, but it's not been linked (none of my history or CV are present).

How do I go about getting this rectified?

Comment: I think that for Careers a dev has to manually associate the accounts.  I have retagged and now a dev (or Juice) will hopefully see and do it.

Comment: If nobody responds after a while, just use the email contact link under "contact us."

Comment: Send an e-mail to careers@stackoverflow.com with your old and new logins so I can merge them. I can't seem to find your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged your two accounts. You should be all set now!