# How can I change my method for logging into Stack Exchange (and remove the old one)?

Tags: support, login

Currently I sign into my Stack Exchange account using my Google login. I'd like to replace this with a different login method, though, so I can still log in to Stack Exchange, but not with Google.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click "add more logins" and pick a different sign-in method. There are some more detailed instructions (with screenshots) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac).

Once that is set up, you will be able to remove your Google credentials from the same dialog: go to "my logins" from your profile and click "remove" beside the credentials you want to take out.