# What does "your own URL" mean and how does it work?

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid

When logged in to https://openid.stackexchange.com, there is "Use your own URL to log in" link:

> [image]

Which leads to this:

> [image]

- What does the URL do?
- How do I use it to log in?
- Why HTML tags?

Comment: @rene I have rewrote the question to have it make more sense, including FHRC. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<link>` tags are for [OpenID delegation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#delegating_authentication), which allows you to use a URL owned by you as the endpoint for an OpenID login, but have the actual authentication handled by the Stack Exchange OpenID provider.

Put another way, it lets you use a custom URL without having to set up your own OpenID endpoint server.

[image: manual openid endpoint login example]

The benefit of this is that if you use a third-party OpenID service and it goes away ([like MyOpenID did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac)), your identifier on all the sites you log into was your own URL, and you can modify the page it points to to reference a different provider without it impacting the sites you were already using.